# Renault Zoe doesn't send SDP Request After SLAC Matching Process

Tags: embedded

We are trying to communicate with Renault Zoe according to DIN SPEC 70121.

We are successfully communciating with the **Hyundai Kona** and **BMW i3** but fail to receive the **SPD Request** with **Renault Zoe**. We are passing the SLAC process with Renault Zoe but we don't recieve any UDP messages afterwards. We are sending the CM_SLAC_MATCH_CNF message as an ethernet unicast message according to DIN SPEC 70121:2014-12, 8.3.3.3.2, Table 2 (noted in Design Guide Combined Charging System V5 - Failures during SLAC - Interruption at SLAC match sequence).

Why can it be that we receive the SDP Request with Kona and i3 but fail to do so with Zoe? Has anyone experienced this behaviour before?

Sniffed SLAC messages with scapy:

*(= '' means the field is filled with zeroes)*

Received from Zoe:

```
###[ CM_SLAC_MATCH_REQ ]###
  ApplicationType= 0
  SecurityType= 0
  MatchVariableFieldLen= 15872
  \VariableField\
   |###[ SLAC_varfield ]###
   |  EVID      = ''
   |  EVMAC     = 7c:bc:84:41:03:3b
   |  EVSEID    = ''
   |  EVSEMAC   = 3e:7e:f1:10:ab:3e
   |  RunID     = '\xd3\xac;\x0f\x17-\xb7+'
   |  RSVD      = ''
```

Send to Zoe:

```
###[ CM_SLAC_MATCH_CNF ]###
  ApplicationType= 0
  SecurityType= 0
  MatchVariableFieldLen= 86
  \VariableField\
   |###[ SLAC_varfield ]###
   |  EVID      = ''
   |  EVMAC     = 7c:bc:84:41:03:3b
   |  EVSEID    = ''
   |  EVSEMAC   = 3e:7e:f1:10:ab:3e
   |  RunID     = '\xd3\xac;\x0f\x17-\xb7+'
   |  RSVD      = ''
   |  NetworkID = '$\x94\xc1\x0c\xbcO\xb5'
   |  Reserved  = 0
   |  NMK       = ''
```

Comment: How is this a valid SO question? It does not appear to be related to embedded systems _programming_ as tagged.

Comment: @Clifford  I mean it is related to embedded since EV communication hardware are embedded devices. But there is no other tag that fits this question, and I don't have 1500 reputation to create a new one. I would tag the network protocols, the related standarts, if they would exist as a tag.

Comment: Don't close this question, since we might find a solution and share it here with the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to send the 2 byte field `MatchVariableFieldLen` in the `CM_SLAC_MATCH_CNF` message in **little-endian** byte order.

From the message that was send by the Renault Zoe, we can see that Zoe sends the `CM_SLAC_MATCH_REQ` with the `MatchVariableFieldLen` as `0x3e 0x00` (`15872 == 0x3e00`). Since this field should be `0x3e` according to DIN SPEC 2014-12, we can see the byte order of this field is **little-endian**. So a reasonable guess was that it expects this field in **little-endian** in the response message.

Result: We received the SDP request and the messages after that.

The **HomePlug GP Specification** does not specify the endianness of this field in clause **11.5.58**. But looking at the example in **Table 11-316**, one would say its big-endian.

It's clear that Zoe interpret this field as little-endian and doesn't accept `0x00 0x56` but accepts `0x56 0x00`.

Kona and i3 either don't complain about this field and accept the message or Zoe's intepreting is false. Either way the cause of the problem has been identified.

Comment: It is not clear that anyone could possibly have arrived at this answer from the information in the question.  Clearly from this answer the question could be made on-topic, by presenting the code in question.